# VimでRailsプロジェクトのタグ作成、ジャンプを実現したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim, ctags

### 達成したいこと

Railsプロジェクトにおけるタグ作成を快適に行いたい

### 背景

最近Vimでuniversal-ctagsを使い始めました。とても便利なのですが、下記2点で悩んでいます。

・Railsプロジェクトのルートディレクトリで `ctags -R` を実行したときに時間がかかり過ぎてしまうこと
・tagsの自動作成プラグインの選定

※ LSPのsolargraphを最初に試してみたのですが、Railsプロジェクトだとジャンプがいまいち思うようにいかないのでctagsを使うことにしたという経緯です。

### 質問

1. gemで定義されたメソッドにも飛べるようにしたい
2. tagsの作成にかかる時間を短くしたい
3. tagsをいい感じのタイミングで自動作成したい

この3件を満たすためには、どのような解決方法、もしくはプラグインが必要でしょうか？

Comment: もしかしたら関連するかもしれません。 - [Ctags with Rails not working - Vi and Vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/14724)

Answer (score 0):

`2`と`3`については、
https://github.com/jsfaint/gen_tags.vim
というプラグインがあるようです。非同期にタグを作成してくれるようですので、要件を満たせるかもしれません。